# Software Center blank screen: gnome keyring problem?

Tags: software-center, xfce

Software Center opens to a blank, grey screen and has to be shut down using the 'not responding' dialogue. Opening software-center using terminal leads to the following error:

```
WARNING: gnome-keyring:: couldn't connect to: /tmp/keyring-bj7Ymn/pkcs11: No such file or directory
```

I found a workaround [here](http://laslow.net/2012/05/06/gnome-keyring-issues-in-ubuntu-12-04/) (I'm running XFCE on Ubuntu 12.04) but I have no file at `/etc/xdg/autostart/gnome-keyring-pkcs11.desktop`.

Now, I'm confused. Any help?

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution at:

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2059844&page=2

> rm -r ~/.cache/software-center

Just needed to clear the cache.